# Error in running a plugin in imageJ

Tags: plugins, imagej, fiji

I am using imageJ (Fiji) version: 2.0.0-rc-43/1.50e
I installed a IHC_Profiler (https://sourceforge.net/projects/ihcprofiler/)
And when I run it, it shows a console with this:

```
Compiling 1 file in    
/var/folders/k2/kdrnsbws5gz8vrt83yjmlbdm0000gn/T/java744586229414007803
/var/folders/k2/kdrnsbws5gz8vrt83yjmlbdm0000gn/T/java744586229414007803/src/main/java/IHC_Profiler.java:10: cannot access java.lang.Object
bad class file:     
ZipFileIndexFileObject[/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]
class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
public class IHC_Profiler implements PlugIn {
```

When I use imageJ 1.48 version, it is okay. I wonder if this problem can be solved?

Comment: The output is saying that java object of Fiji is compiled with Java8 while the plugin is compiled with Java6. You need to compile the plugin with JDK 8 so that the Java version becomes equivalent.

Comment: Thank you. Since there is no further update of this plugin, I think I would I have to stick with the older version.

Answer (score 1):

You are running Fiji with Java 8, but without the Java-8 update site enabled.

The easiest solution is to [download a fresh Fiji](http://fiji.sc/#download), which comes with the Java-8 update site enabled out of the box.

See this guide for details:

- http://imagej.net/2016-05-10_-_ImageJ_HOWTO_-_Java_8,_Java_6,_Java_3D